# How to create swift package and a companion app side-by-side

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I'm trying to accomplish the same package organization as this one https://github.com/pointfreeco/swift-composable-architecture. The features I would like to achieve are the following:

1. Companion app and package live in the same workspace and can be edited side-by-side

[image]

2. Companion app is hosted in the same repo, but it is not downloaded as part of the package checkout

[image]

I've tried:

1. Starting with an empty workspace, then adding a package to it, but then `Package.swift` won't be at the root of the repo, so this won't work.
2. Starting with the package `File > New > Package`. Then created the empty workspace in the same folder. Opened it and drag the package folder onto it. Then added a new app project linking it with the package I will be building. It all seems to work fine. However, now I'm leaving with the `Example` folder inside my package and I cannot just simply delete the reference to it. Only lets me delete the entire folder.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get to the same result I wanted to achieve following these steps:

1. Start with the package File > New > Package. Close this project.
2. Create an empty workspace and save it to the package's root directory.
3. From Finder, drag your package folder into the workspace.
4. Open workspace again. Add a new App project to it and again save it to package's root directory. Close this workspace.
5. Go to your App project root and add an empty package file like:

```
// swift-tools-version:5.5

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
   name: "Example",
   products: []
)
```

6. Open the workspace again. Drag the package into the app project's root.
7. Select your app project's > Build Phases > Link Binary with Libraries and add your package

You should now be able to compile the app and make any references to the package you will be building from it.
Users checking out your package will not get the app's project.

Answer (score 0):

Companion app `Should NOT BE` hosted in the same repository. 
I suggest creating another repository for your design-system package and adding it as a cloud package.

If you insist on having one repository for your package and project, create the package and add it into the project's root directory only by dragging and dropping.

Then use `git add.`, then commit and push it.

After that, you can add design-system package locally. Follow these steps below:

1. File
2. Add Packages...
3. Add Local...
4. Select your package (Which is in your root directory)
5. After Adding the package, Add it in `Targets` > `'YourProject'` > `General` > `Frameworks`

Comment: When I say companion app, I'm actually referring to an app that showcases the features of the package, it's not the main app. Given that clarification, would you still be holding that such companion app should not be hosted in the same repository? What's the reason?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, the companion app is a demo app for your package; I suggest creating an `example` folder and adding the application there.
For example, check: https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher
you can see the Demo folder.

Comment: That will download the example app as part of the package.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I recommend, as demonstrated in https://github.com/MacPaw/OpenAI 's structure (also derived from `swift-composable-architecture`'s.

```
Root
|-- Package.swift << Your package
|-- Sources/ << containing your package sources
|-- Demo << Companion app
  |-- Demo.xcodeProj
  |-- App/... << the wiring code of your demo project
  |-- DemoPackage
    |- Package.swift << Your demo app's package, it should declare dependency on the package of your Root ../..
    |- OtherFiles.swift
```

To summarize,

1. Create the demo app folder on the same level as your package sources.
2. Inside Demo app, create a new package `DemoPackage`, which depends on your Root package `../..`. This package can contain the bulk of your business logic of your companion app.
3. Add the `DemoPackage` locally to your demo app project. Add light wiring wrapper to reference your `DemoPackage`.

This way, you can write demo app inside a package you offer.